# Framework not found using cocoapods and tvOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, tvos

I have a project with two targets, one is iOS, the other tvOS. After creating a podfile that will work for both of them, and I'm using cocoapods 1.0.0.beta.3 so apple TV stuff works, I can build the iOS project fine, but I get errors when trying to build the Apple TV app. specifically `ld: framework not found Alamofire`

here's my podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

def common_pods
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'Raven', :git => 'https://github.com/getsentry/raven-objc.git', :tag => '1.0.1'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
  pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7.5'
  pod 'JSQCoreDataKit'
  pod 'MBProgressHUD', :git => 'https://github.com/smejkpa7/MBProgressHUD.git'
end

target 'Proj' do
  use_frameworks!
  platform :ios, '8.0'
  common_pods
end

target 'ProjTvOS' do
  use_frameworks!
  platform :tvos, '9.0'
  common_pods
end
```

I also get this warning
`ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/codymace/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Proj-gditpcvccsqwvhekifzrooriaezm/Build/Products/Debug-appletvos/Pods-ProjTvOS'`

I noticed that that framework doesn't exist, because it's actually Pods_ProjTvOS with an underscore instead of a dash. This is what I get out of the box from cocoapods though.

I also just noticed that the pod frameworks are not being added to the build directory. So I copied them over from the iphoneos directory and it built successfully. But then I get issues installing on a device, I'm thinking because I need to clean the project but that removes the frameworks.

Using Xcode 7.2.1 by the way.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4):

I'm using this and it works

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :tvos, '9.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
end

target 'MyAppTests' do
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
end

target 'MyAppUITests' do
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
end
```

I'm guessing you're opening workspace, not project ?! I'm also running it for tvos and xcode 7.3

Comment: I don't know why this answer have 0 upvotes, this WORKS FOR ME!!! thanks +1